# Indirect ► Transpose ► Importrange = It is not a valid cell/range reference - not an expert, need help

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, importrange

I'm trying to get a range from another spreadsheet, to appear depending on an ID number placed in the current sheet, I've been doing that for other data within the sheet and spreadsheet, but whenever I need to make the INDIRECT formula place a IMPORTRANGE formula, it just doesn't work.

`A1` in the current sheet is being used as an ID number, representing a Row in other sheets and spreadsheets.

`=INDIRECT("=TRANSPOSE(IMPORTRANGE(""<SpreadsheetLink>"",""<Sheet>!B"&A1&":K"&A1&"""))")`

INDIRECT is giving the current output: `=TRANSPOSE(IMPORTRANGE("<SpreadsheetLink>","<Sheet>!B3:K3"))` saying "It is not a valid cell/range reference."

"3" being the value in `A1` and the current ID number

Pasting that same output in another cell works just fine, but I want the ID number to be changed eventually and I don't want to enter the formula every single time since it will be very time consuming in the long run.

Why Isn't it possible?
It's just not?
But why not?

EDIT:

Just tried something from another post:

`=IMPORTRANGE("<SpreadsheetLink>",INDIRECT("""<Sheet>!B"&A1&":K"&A1&""""))`

Which in gave me this: Function INDIRECT parameter 1 value is `"Estudio!B3:K3"`. It is not a valid cell/range reference.

↑ That being the same error, but without the formula, maybe the INDIRECT formula is reacting to the `<Sheet>!<Range>` format?

Answer (score 1):

For the record, If I didn't post this, I wouldn't have found the answer.

`=TRANSPOSE(IMPORTRANGE("<SpreadsheetLink>","<Sheet>!B"&A1&":K"&A1&""))`

Turns out I didn't even need the INDIRECT Formula at all... I barely get it.